# How to read properties value from interface in java

Tags: java, spring, aws-lambda

I would like to read **testvalue** from properties file in java, can someone please help
Following is my code

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunction;

public interface LambdaPDFService {
    @LambdaFunction(functionName="**testValue**")
    Map<String, String> setResponse(LambdaPdfRequest input);
}
```

I have tried below annotation, and e.tc but it's not working

@PropertySources(@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"))

Comment: Any value in annotations need to be compile-time constants. It's impossible for any dynamic value to be used, including values from properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read in an interface.

You can read in a concrete class annotated as a @Service (or @Component). Assuming application.properties includes `lambda.function.name=foo`

```
@Service
public class LambdaPDFServiceImpl implements LambdaPDFService {
    @LambdaFunction(functionName="${lambda.function.name}")
    Map<String, String> setResponse(LambdaPdfRequest input) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```